# Simplifying covariance matrices in distributions

Tags: matrices, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

In the multivariate Gaussian distribution, it is required that the covariance matrix be positive semidefinite. I have read that a positive semidefinite matrix $\Sigma$ [can be written](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_sym_psd.html) as $LL^{T}$. I [have also seen](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aScOc5ANwq3sJ%3awww.mit.tut.fi/MIT-3030/MDA2_lecture4-5_07.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=mx&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgX1dI-ppgLL6C2I9sTaJqEY4VsENJXYS9SzfeR6TMozEM1zCYGgImV3BC49jWMMPLn4UwEibgVii9GQ4LeRMVsOUxTVC06gJkXTB4X1hPrcswl5MoWwzru1bJnosvCzQNgKQG2&sig=AHIEtbRD54YpcT6qDFg01FWM1BN_JbZZNg) that $\Sigma=(C^{T}C)^{-1}$ where $C$ is positive definite (is this true?). However, I'm entirely sure why this is true.

I want to know what facts do we know about positive semidefinite matrices that can be used in order to manipulate a multivariate Gaussian or similar distributions. For example, in a Gaussian distribution:

$$f(x)=\exp{\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\}}$$

we can use $\Sigma^{-1}=C^{T}C$ (although I'm not entirely certain this is correct). Therefore, a change of variable $y = C (x-\mu)$  can be used to write $f(x)$ as:

$$f(x)=\exp{\{-\frac{1}{2}y^{T}y\}}$$

Another example could be using $\Sigma^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^{D} \frac{1}{\lambda_{i}}u_{i}u_{i}^{T}$ where $u_{i}$ are the eigenvectors of $\Sigma$ and $\lambda_{i}$ its eigenvalues. This expression also can be used to simplify $f(x)$.

What other representations are there for $\Sigma^{-1}$? Or what is the correct procedure in the examples I described above?

**UPDATE:**

A third example could be simply taking $\Sigma^{-1} = \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2} T}\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ (because $\Sigma$ is symmetric) and change variables with $y = \Sigma^{-1/2}(x-\mu)$.

Initiallly I had written a fourth option with $\Sigma$ as $G^{T}DG$ with $G$ as a orthogonal matrix and $D$ as an diagonal matrix containing $\Sigma$'s eigenvalues. I think that's wrong and the correct decomposition should be $\Sigma=G\Lambda G^{T}$, however this still produces issues because a change of variable $y=G^{T}(x-\mu)$ leads to a differential volume in the following form:

$$dy_{1}dy_{2}...dy_{n} = |G^{T}|dx_{1}dx_{2}...dx_{n}$$

but the determinant of $G$ might be 1 or -1, which is not good.

Thanks!

Comment: If the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is positive semidefinite and not positive definite, then there is no $n$-variate joint _density_ function and the expression $f(x)=\exp{\{-\frac{1}{2}y^{T}y\}}$ does not mean what you think it means. When $\Sigma_{n\times n}$ is positive semidefinite, there exist $m < n$ independent standard Gaussian random variables $\mathbf y = (y_1, \ldots y_m)^T$ such that $$\mathbf x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)^T = C\mathbf y + \mathbf \mu$$ for some $C$ such that $\Sigma = C^TC$. Note that $C$ is a $n\times m$ non-square matrix. $\mathbf x$ does _not_ have a joint density.

Comment: That seems like an affine property. However, I'm not sure if that's related to taking $\Sigma = (C^{T}C)^{-1})$

Comment: If you like, take $\mu =0$ to simplify your life and make things linear instead of affine. But you are missing seeing the forest because of the trees. If $\Sigma$ is positive semi-definite, then the expression $$f(x)=\exp{\{-\frac{1}{2}(x-\mu)^{T}\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)\}}$$ is _invalid_; these $n$ Gaussian random variables are _not jointly continuous_ and do not enjoy a $n$-variate joint density.

Comment: Uhm, it's weird I haven't heard that before. Most of the write-ups insist that semidefinite is enough. Well, let's suppose positive definite then.